Integrate numerically over implicit complex contour
I'm trying to numerically evaluate the following integral:
$$
\int_0^\infty dt\ e^{-(a+i\alpha) t}(1+e^{-t})^{-(b+i\beta)},
$$
where $a,b$ are some rational numbers and $\alpha,\beta$ are relatively small (I know this can be computed exactly as the Euler beta function, but it's just a toy model for more complicated integrals). Now, my interest lies in the regions of parameter space where $a,b$ are negative rational/integers, for which the integrand diverges. Thus, I want to deform the contour to the complex plane. Specifically, for the first part of the integral I'm looking to integrate over a contour which starts at the origin and follows a path of stationary phase/steepest descent, which would eventually end in the branch point $t=-i\pi$, see the image representing a ComplexPlot of the integrand where I have drawn the contour in black (I would stop earlier than that).

However, as far as I can tell, there is no direct analytic parametrization of this contour, and I'm not sure how to formulate it to Mathematica, since there are several disconnected line where the integrand has the same phase as the origin $t=0$. How should I proceed?

I figure I'm having a brainfreeze, but if $\gamma(0)=0$ and $a$ and $b$ are rational, then doesn't the path $\gamma$ traces lie on $Arg(z) = 0$?

I came to the same conclusion as @MichaelE2. This is in general a confusing question.

You need to be more specific about how to choose your contour. For example, where  is your path $\gamma$ in the picture produced by With[{a = -2, b = -3},   ComplexContourPlot[Arg[Exp[-a z] (1 + Exp[-z])^(-b)], {z, 5}]] ?

@DanielLichblau thanks for the feedback. I edited the question to hopefully make it more clear what I'm trying to do.

@MichaelE2,  not exactly, I edited the question so hopefully now it's more clear

@A.Kato thanks. Unfortunately there is no analytic expression for the contour I'm looking for, but hopefully now with the edited question you can understand what I was trying to ask

@Marcosko:  How about generating an array of Arg[integrand] over a desired region, picking out points with the same argument, then fitting the data to a desired curve as a function of t as the contour?

Mathematica say: $$\int_0^{\infty } e^{t (-a-i \alpha )} \left(1+e^{-t}\right)^{-b-i \beta } , dt=\frac{, _2F_1(a+i \alpha ,b+i \beta ;1+a+i \alpha ;-1)}{a+i \alpha }$$ for $a>0$.

@MariuszIwaniuk Indeed! Now try it with a<0 and let me know what you get :)

for $a<0$ Integral of E^(-t (a+I [Alpha])) (1+E^-t)^(-b-I [Beta]) does not
converge on {0,[Infinity]} !

@MariuszIwaniuk well, that is partially right. You can analytically continue your result for a>0 (which can be rewritten more elegantly as Euler's Beta function) into negative values of a. This is the same as deforming your integration contour in the complex plane, and you can even check it works numerically!

@Marcosko " it works numerically!" give us the code? and update the question ?

@MariuszIwaniuk just try to NIntegrate from 0 to some positive number t_* (in this case it doesn't matter) and then NIntegrate along a line going down the imaginary axis from t_* to (t_* - i \infty) (-\infty here just means a very large negative number). You can then compare with the result from Gamma[a]Gamma[b]/Gamma[a+b]/2. This is just standard knowledge

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
